# Custom tab bar items

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

I've created 5 custom tab bar items inside `TabBarViewController`. design looks fine but Tab Bars go black screen after choosing, they dont change the view controllers. here's the code of `TabBarViewController` with some screenshots. any solution will be appericated

```swift
        let controller1 = UIViewController()
        controller1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 1)
        let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
        nav1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "First", image: UIImage(systemName: "house.fill"), tag: 1)
        nav1.title = "home"
        nav1.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        nav1.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        nav1.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        
        let controller2 = UIViewController()   // If i try to change it to custom view controller it still doesn't work
        controller2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 2)
        let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller2)
        let controller3 = tabViewController()
        let nav3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller3)
        nav3.title = "Create"
        nav3.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(named: "violet")
        let controller4 = UIViewController()
        controller4.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 4)
        let nav4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller4)
        let controller5 = UIViewController()
        controller5.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .contacts, tag: 5)
        let nav5 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller5)
        viewControllers = [nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4, nav5]
        setupMiddleButton()
    }

     // code below is third tab bar styled. not to get confused

    func setupMiddleButton() {
        let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))
        var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
        menuButtonFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - 50
        menuButtonFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
        menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
        let image = UIImage(systemName: "plus.rectangle.fill", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 45, weight: .semibold))
        menuButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        //shadows
        menuButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        menuButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 4)
        menuButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        //
        menuButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        menuButton.tintColor = UIColor(named: "violet")
        menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height
        view.addSubview(menuButton)
        menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

as I said in my code's comment anytime I change e.g. `controller2` to my created view controller it doesn't work. screenshots below:

view controller i expect to see after clicking tab bar item:
[image]

view I see:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help, I tried to recreate your app:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let tabBarVc = UITabBarController()
        
        let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1())
        let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2())
        let vc3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc3())
        let vc4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc4())
        let vc5 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc5())
        
        vc1.title = "home"
        vc2.title = "contacts"
        vc3.title = "create"
        vc4.title = "contacts"
        vc5.title = "contacts"
        
        tabBarVc.setViewControllers([vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4,vc5], animated: false)
        tabBarVc.tabBar.backgroundColor = .white
        
        guard let items = tabBarVc.tabBar.items else {
            return
        }
        
        let images = ["house","person.crop.circle.fill","plus.rectangle.fill","person.crop.circle.fill","person.crop.circle.fill"]
        for x in 0..<items.count {
            items[x].image = UIImage(systemName: images[x])
        }
        
        tabBarVc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(tabBarVc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


}

class vc1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            app.backgroundColor = .white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
        title = "home"
        
    }
}

class vc2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple
        title = "contacts"
    }
}

class vc3: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        title = "Create"
    }
}

class vc4: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        title = "contacts"
    }
}

class vc5: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        title = "contacts"
    }
}
```